# Regular Express (RegEx) and sed/gsed question

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am attempting to replace the following pattern in multiple files in a source directory

- source/a.txt
- source/b.txt
- source/c.txt

Pattern to match:

```
    Body: |6+
       
      
       
      
      some text
      some more text
```

I want to change this pattern to:

```
    Body: |      
      some text
      some more text
```

So my sed command is attempting to match `Body: |6+`.  I am using this sed command

```
gsed 's/Body: |[6+-]*/Body: |/' source/a.txt > test.yaml
```

This works to replace `Body: |6+` or `Body: |+` or `Body: |-`, which are all possible patterns in my source files.  However, what I have yet to accomplish is removing all the blank lines (have spaces) until I hit the first line with text.

Another sed command I tried, but did not work, was the following:

```
gsed -e '/Body: |6/{
  :a
  N
  /\n$/d
  /^[[:space:]]*$/ba
}' "lisa Zackheim.txt" > test.yaml
```

I am running this on MacOS.

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`? Operating on multiple lines is easier with `awk`.

Comment: Did not have to use `sed`, but I grabbed for `sed` first as I have used it in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some magic here extending your solution using `//`:

```
gsed 's/Body: |[6+-]*/Body: |/; //,/[^[:space:]]/ {//!d}' a.txt
```

`//` means "prior match" so it's a great shorthand to repeat your regexes here in exactly the way that you need.

- `//,/[^[:space:]]/` -- in the range of lines from the one matching `/Body: |[6+-]*/` to the first line with a non-space character:
- `//!d` delete the line if it is neither of the matches that delineate the range (there's a sort of short-circuit behavior here.)

Comment: This solution worked!  I am very thankful for your time and knowledge.  Your `RegEx` and `sed` skills are next level.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(Body: \|)6?[+-](\n)[^[:alpha:]]+\n/\1\2/' source/*.txt > test.yaml
```

Or using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^ +?$/d;s/(Body: \|)6?[+-]/\1/' source/*.txt > test.yaml
```

**Output**

```
$ cat test.yaml
    Body: |
      some text
      some more text
```

Comment: Thanks, neither of these solutions worked for me.  The `GNU sed` did not generate any changes.  The `sed` produced the following error: ```sed: 1: "/^ +?$/d;s/(Body: \|)6? ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid```